# Include my own icons into my eclipse android project

Tags: android, eclipse, icons

Anybody know how to include and use own icons in an android eclipse project. I found out how to convert them from ico to png files but other than that, I cannot use them in my project, I am simply lost.

Please help :)

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Drag and drop you png files to the mdpi folder.(For a medium density display)

You can access them simply by `R.drawable.youiconname`

[Also refer to this article](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html)